# CTRL and ALT keys mapped to Shift for some reason

Tags: drivers, keyboard, keyboard-layout, usbhid

I installed Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm loving it. However, when playing a game called Garry's Mod I noticed that my <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys on my wired keyboard were both being detected as <kbd>Shift</kbd>. I looked at the keyboard layout chart and confirmed this. I also noticed that my Windows, or <kbd>Super</kbd> Key, <kbd>Right CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Right ALT</kbd> are all being mapped to <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>.

They're all working perfect, they're just being detected wrong. I have selected the United States layout which is what my keyboard is supposed to be and is in Windows. Can anyone help? My keyboard is being detected as a SONiX USB Keyboard (the actual keyboard brand is Avazz).

- my `xev -event keyboard` output is this for every single one:

  ```
  KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
      root 0xdc, subw 0x0, time 2446369, (730,547), root:(795,599),
      state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XFilterEvent returns: False
  ```

  The only thing that changes is the time.
- The `sudo evtest` command shows all the modifier keys as

  ```
  type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e1v type 1 (EV_KEY), code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT), value 0
  ```
- for `lsusb`, the driver it's using is the `usbhid` driver.

  `lsusb` shows something confusing; the same port as my keyboard is being shown in other commands is showing up in `lsusb` as my wireless mouse's driver, `Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`. This may be the problem, but I'm probably simply mistaken in what port it is on. Due to this, I'm not sure what driver is what. I'm going to post all of them, although this might be annoying. I have a separate keyboard plugged in along side my main one to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, or <kbd>ALT</kbd> by the way, so don't be confused by the Logitech Classic Keyboard Driver.

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
  Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic Keyboard 200
  Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
  Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0480:0200 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. 
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6340 Microdia 
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
  Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  ```

  For `lsusb -t`, the driver being used is `usbhid`.
- `for i in $(ls /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/); do echo -ne "$i\t"; more /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/$i; done` is:

  ```
  ignoreled   0
  mousepoll   0
  quirks  (null),(null),(null),(null)
  ```
- I don't think you need this since I said it's `usbhid`, but here's it anyways.

  `for i in $(ls /sys/module/hid/parameters/); do echo -ne "$i\t"; more /sys/module/hid/parameters/$i; done`'s output.

  debug   0
  ignore_special_drivers  0
- `modinfo usbhid`'s output is:

  ```
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.18.3-031803-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbhid.ko
  license:        GPL
  description:    USB HID core driver
  author:         Jiri Kosina
  author:         Vojtech Pavlik
  author:         Andreas Gal
  srcversion:     A395FA22EA2729BAC1557C9
  alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic03isc*ip*in*
  depends:        hid
  intree:         Y
  vermagic:       3.18.3-031803-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
  sig_key:        29:DB:FD:FC:5A:CC:82:3C:C5:2C:39:4C:C1:C7:4C:01:C3:BE:BF:78
  sig_hashalgo:   sha512
  parm:           mousepoll:Polling interval of mice (uint)
  parm:           ignoreled:Autosuspend with active leds (uint)
  parm:           quirks:Add/modify USB HID quirks by specifying  quirks=vendorID:productID:quirks where vendorID, productID, and quirks are all in 0x-prefixed hex (array of charp)
  ```
- `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/2u > /tmp/usb.mon.out` is telling me not found even though I changed `2` to my bus ID. What am I doing wrong here? Clarify if you can please, kinda confused there. I tried putting `2`, `02` and `002`. The output of 
  `sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/` is 
  `0s  0u    1s  1t  1u  2s  2t  2u`

Comment: @Sneetsher  Done; they both show as the same thing for that too. Resulting code is in the description.

Comment: @Sneetsher Done

Comment: Does Grégory's answer works for you?

Comment: Answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift

Answer (score 6):

My keyboard is a Perixx P1800. It as the same lsusb identification (0c45:7603 Microdia)
Apparently, it uses the same board also as the azio L70 keyboard.

The linux driver for the keyboard was hand-made and is available at [this address](http://swoogan.blogspot.fr/2014/09/azio-l70-keyboard-linux-driver.html).

On Debian, it works very well for me (after `update-initramfs`) except for a single key close to Enter (* in Azerty keyboard, the * of the keypad is working well).

Comment: I wrote the driver. Can you send me details about which key isn't working and what layout you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I bore with it for months but then I attempted to find the way to solve it.

Here is the driver; although my keyboard isn't that brand it worked perfectly. I hope it solves your problem too. The Driver and instructions are HERE:

https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd

PD: I didn't write the driver, I just found it.

-Edited after the suggestions of a #GrammarNazy xD