# ALT and CTRL behave like SHIFT

Tags: keyboard

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago and I noticed that both of my <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and both of my <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys behave exactly the same as the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

I have tried changing input method, but it didn't help.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?
I am using ubuntu on dekstop pc
Keyboard is Tracer hellway

Answer (score 0):

Appears to a possible Duplicate of [CTRL and ALT works as SHIFT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift). 
Anyway try this:-

1. Install driver from https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mercurial build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
   hg clone https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd
   cd aziokbd
   sudo ./install.sh dkms
   ```
2. Add kernel option to grub to prevent `usbhid` from being used for this keyboard. Append:

   ```
   usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4
   ```

   to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.

   Example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4"
   ```
3. Update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot

**References:**

- [CTRL and ALT keys mapped to Shift for some reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572394/ctrl-and-alt-keys-mapped-to-shift-for-some-reason)
- [dkms Installed kernel module but not working after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605251/dkms-installed-kernel-module-but-not-working-after-reboot)
- [Prevent usbhid from claiming USB device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device)

Orignally answered by [user.dz](https://askubuntu.com/a/648809/884818)

Comment: nope it didnt help

Comment: Can you tell me the keycodes you get when you use ``xev -event keyboard`` and press the shift, ctrl and alt key.

Comment: this is what i get after pressing CTRL ALT or SHIFT                                                                                               
         KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 28479517, (100,-167), root:(291,403),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: @DaukšasLukas Is it the same for all the keys? You seem to have provided only 1.

Comment: Shift =   KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 39749349, (1345,488), root:(1376,547),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 39749461, (1345,488), root:(1376,547),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: Ctrl= KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 39865243, (134,80), root:(165,139),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 39865411, (134,80), root:(165,139),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: Alt = KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 39902250, (935,306), root:(966,365),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e7, subw 0x0, time 39902314, (935,306), root:(966,365),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: It appears That your keyboard sends same keycode for all the keys, there is no way the kernel can differentiate between the keys, You will need a proprietary driver. (which might not be available for linux.) I don't understand Why Manufaturars don't make HID compliant Devices.

Comment: If i would switch my keyboard maybe it will fix it selft then?

Comment: @DaukšasLukas It Should, you may also try finding drivers (my answer linked to a set of Driver for keyboard which had the same problem).