# Kalashnikov AK-700 Armaggeddon Keyboard doesn't work with Ubuntu OS but works fine with Windows

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, compatibility

I bought a keyboard yesterday and I noticed some of the keys behave differently, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the Windows key act like <kbd>shift</kbd>.

In the setting, I have tried different languages and layouts but then the problem persists. btw, when I plugin the keyboard in a laptop with a windows OS all keys work fine.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.

keyboard: Kalashnikov AK-700 Armaggeddon Wired USB

I have tried plenty of suggested solutions including [ALT and CTRL behave like SHIFT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086153/alt-and-ctrl-behave-like-shift)

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me
thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it seems that some types of keyboards are not compatible with Linux OS.

Comment: "Don't adquire/buy/bring/use hardware that not have support for the system you want to use". First of all, try to find and read some info before do it =). As much as pretty/wonderfull/useful/modern/comfortable it looks like =). Good luck !